# Send API data from Backend to Frontend in real time with Django and React

Tags: django, react-native, django-rest-framework

I am working and I need your help. I am working on a website with Django with DRF on the backend and react on the frontend. I need a way of sending api data to the client whenever any changes are made. The data is only coming from the database, the client is only viewing the progress. What options do I have to acheive. I need it to handle a large number on people. Say 20 000. Please your help will do a lot for me.

Comment: you can use `socket.io`

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Websockets. See Django-channels for Django implementation, on React side you will have to setup Websocket connection to your Django and listen for messages.
2. Use long polling, or periodic polling of data. Basically this is a process when your React app sends requests to backend periodically or makes a request that lasts forever.

Comment: Please share any resources where I can learn more about long polling. I dont seem to understand the concept as explained in some articles

Comment: For Django see Django-channels https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/
also I see some long pooling related questions and answers on stack overflow like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41858300/how-to-do-http-long-polling-with-django-channels Hope this helps